# why search engines need to reindex periodically but databases don't?

Tags: database, search, database-design, full-text-search, search-engine

For example , search engines such as Sphinx , Lucene must merge there indexes periodically , but index of database can be updated dynamically . Why must the index of search engine be merged?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Sphinx but I believe the answer to this question will not be related to it.

First, why databases do not need updates periodically? This is because of database is the major data store for the applications most of the time. By this I mean, if you create, delete or update any data; that data is the means of a database record. You're removing data from there to get rid of it within the application or you first get the data from database to update since old version is kept there. All this indicates that databases are being updated all the time and your data is always up-to-date there.

Why an index of a search engine needs periodic reindexing? Index is the data store for a search engine basically that you're processing your data, putting it into index and then retrieving it by the means of your search system. That index is your secondary data resource. This does not hold for all applications but most of the time, you have database as primary resource that is being synchronized with your application as I explained above and then index where you're not reflecting all changes in real-time. Then you find your data in index a little bit outdated according to the database. That reindexing step is necessary for you to keep your data resources consistent.

As I said this explanation does not hold for all applications but it can give you the basic idea.

ps: You have a "index of database" phrase in your question but it is totally a different topic.